# Fixing Macro to Combine Contiguous Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a calendar right now based on months/quarters and I'm on the final steps and one of the last things I need to figure out is how to combine cells with duplicate values and merge them so they flow across the calendar fluidly.

What I have now: [image]

What I want: [image]

I'm a newbie VBA coder but have some experience with C# so I have been looking around and put together this code but I'm not sure if I got the logic right or if it even works properly:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MergeContiguousValues(col As Long)

   Dim start As Range
   Dim finish As Range


   Set start = Cells(1, col)
   Set finish = start

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Do While start <> ""

      Do While start = finish.Offset(1, 0)
         Set finish = finish.Offset(1, 0)
      Loop

      If start.Address <> finish.Address Then
         Range(start, finish).Merge
         Range(start, finish).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      End If

      Set start = finish.Offset(1, 0)
      Set finish = start

   Loop

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Or where I'm going wrong?

I'm using `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND` formulas for the calendar pulling information from separate sheets that carry data from an entry form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `Areas` property of `Range` object like follows:

```
Public Sub MergeContiguousValues(calendarColumns As Range, calendarStartRow As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim area As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With calendarColumns
        For i = calendarStartRow To LastRow(calendarColumns, calendarStartRow)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(i)) > 0 Then
                For Each area In .Rows(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Areas
                    With area
                        .Merge
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With
                Next area
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

and here follows the `LastRow()` function:

```
Function LastRow(rng As Range, minRow As Long) As Long
    With rng.Parent
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, rng.columns).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            LastRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row
        End With
    End With
    If LastRow < minRow Then LastRow = minRow
End Function
```

as per your example a possible usage could be:

```
Sub main()
    MergeContiguousValues Worksheets("calendar").Range("D:O"), 4
End Sub
```

where I assumed "calendar" as the name of the worksheet with the calendar: change it as per your needs

Comment: @adrenom did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.  I tested it in a blank worksheet with the same value in cells A1 thru D1...  Hope this helps!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MergeContiguousValues()

Dim start As Range
Dim finish As Range
Dim sVal As String
Dim fVal As String

'replace Cells(1, 1) with your passed variables
Set start = Cells(1, 1)
Set finish = start

'set values for the starting and finishing cell
sVal = start.Value
fVal = finish.Value

'check each column until the name is no longer the same
Do While sVal = fVal

    Set finish = finish.Offset(0, 1)
    fVal = finish.Value

Loop

'backup one column
Set finish = finish.Offset(0, -1)

'clear all values and only place value in start range
Range(start, finish).Value = ""
Range(start.Address).Value = sVal

'instead of merging, how about aligning across the start and finish range
Range(start, finish).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this works, I just tested it using the same example you had however in my specific case it doesn't. Do you think it may have something to do with the formulas? When they are actual values instead of formulas it seems to work.Tried your example again using formulas and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @adrenom Yeah, my example hard codes the values.  Can you be more specific in what's happening when running the macro on your spreadsheet? What's your formula... and what error message appears?  Does the formula need to stay or is it ok for it to get hard coded?

Comment: When I run the macro nothing happens, no errors.

My formula is: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",'HI Project Database'!D2)), ('HI Project    Database'!$B2&" - "&'HI Project Database'!$A2), "") -- I'm not sure if I can move it somewhere else as the calendar is pulling specific information from 2 separate spreadsheets in order to plug in the Project Name and Name of the Person who owns it. I'm not sure where I could move it so it could be hardcoded as it would still need to be referenced and then it would become a formula again, correct?